# Javascript, Jquery works fine in localhost but not in the deployed site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote a simple signup page, and validated it with pure **javascript** and **jquery**. I also used **font-awesome** icons to show status of the input value. It worked fine with all the user agents(*I tested it with a chrome extension*). but after putting the files to a server it is not working with any of the user agents.

> issues :
>
> 1. Some user agents not showing font awesome icons, but the scripts are working.
> 2. In some user agents the icons as well as the scripts both are not working.

I don't no where the issue is.

```
    <head>
      <title>TicketIsle Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/get_post.js"></script>
    </head>
```

the above is how I put the scripts and style files.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your page is in secure (https) some browsers dont allow you explicitly to download scripts or styles from non-secure (http) pages.

This syntax should be used to avoid this protocol issue:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This is protocol agnostic i.e. it will work with both `http` and `https`.

Comment: so what should i do? do i need to download the scripts manually rather than linking to a cdn?

Comment: @CharlesRajendran Please check the updated answer. You should use protocol agnostic url's for both external scripts and stylesheets.

Comment: Thankyou, console also print the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to us downloaded file rather using CDN.

You should put all the script tag bottom of your page and put all CSS file on top of page in head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link href="fonts/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
 <main>
 <body>

     </body>    
  </main> 



  <!--    -------------------------------------  -->
<!--    Javascript Includes  -->
<!--    ----------------------`enter code here`---------------  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 

</html>
```